# how do i get the mouseover effect showing the title of the image in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```js
var i = 0
$('#knopToggle').on('click', function () {
    i++
    var imgAttributes = {
        'src': 'kitten' + i + '.jpg',
        'title': 'Afbeelding van poes' + i,
        'alt': 'Afbeelding van poes' + i
    }
    if (i > 2) {
        i = 0
    };
    $('#imgKitten').attr(imgAttributes)
}
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="kitten1.jpg" alt="" id="imgKitten" height="200px" width="200px">
<div id="divResult"></div>
<button id="knopToggle">wissel afbeelding</button>
```

it doesn't show the title with mouseover on images.
How do i get to show the title attribute with mouseover?

Comment: Your code snippet works fine for me - does exactly what you say it doesn't do - sets the `title` then pointing at the (broken) image shows that title in a tooltip

Answer (score -1):

If you inspect the DOM you'll see that `title` is not set.

You'll need `element.prop('title', 'something')` to set the Title for a DOM element.

Place your mouse over the image, wait 2 seconds and the title will appear:

```js
var i = 0
$('#knopToggle').on('click', function () {
    i++
    var imgAttributes = {
        'src': 'kitten' + i + '.jpg',
        'alt': 'Afbeelding van poes' + i
    }
    if (i > 2) {
        i = 0
    };
    
    const el = $('#imgKitten');
    
    el.attr(imgAttributes);
    el.prop('title', 'Afbeelding van poes' + i);
    
}
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="kitten1.jpg" alt="" id="imgKitten" height="200px" width="200px">
<div id="divResult"></div>
<button id="knopToggle">wissel afbeelding</button>
```

---

Keep in mind that you [*You might not need jQuery*](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/), here is the native Javascript version of the above:

```js
var i = 0
const el = document.querySelector('#imgKitten');

document.querySelector('#knopToggle').addEventListener('click', () => {
  
    i++
    if (i > 2) {
        i = 0
    };
    
    el.src = 'kitten' + i + '.jpg';
    el.title = 'Afbeelding van poes' + i;
});
```

```html
<img src="kitten1.jpg" alt="" id="imgKitten" height="200px" width="200px">
<div id="divResult"></div>
<button id="knopToggle">wissel afbeelding</button>
```